# Format ToC for thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titlesec

I apologize for the unspecified and broad question but I have no way to be specific. I'm looking to generate the TOC and List of Figure, List of Table according to the format required by my school.

[image]

[image]

I have been trying with `titlesec` but I can't get some details working. Specifically the followings:

- no bold-face;
- The line 'CHAPTER     Page' has to appear on every page of the ToC. Same with the line 'Figure    Page' for the LoF and 'TABLE   Page' for the LoT;
- Single spacing between chapter and its section but double spacing between chapters
- If the title is more than one line long, it should follow the format in Figure 2.1, i.e there are spaces before 1884

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: As your four issues cover four separate problems, please remove three of them from this question and post them as new questions. This way, other users looking for help can find solutions more easily. (The fact that they're all for the same project you're working on doesn't really matter here.) Also don't forget to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for each question. Before posting, make sure the questions haven't been asked on here already via searching.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm using \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

Comment: Can you switch to the book document class?

Comment: How should a regular chapter heading look like?

Comment: Oh, everything is 12pt. The chapter heading in the text should be at center and all capital. I'm using this \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{20pt}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{0pt}{\small}
  
 \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

but I can't not get section, etc unbold.

Comment: Delete `\bfseries` from the definitions. If other issues remain unsolved, since this is a rather separate matter, I think the best way to go is to accept an answer to this question and to post a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how). In the new question you can provide a MWE with your current code and link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

1. I used the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) packages to customize the ToC, LoF and LoT titles and entries as required. Firther customization might be required for the titles, but this might depend on the general layout for the chapter titles and this information was not provided in the question.
2. The [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) packge was used to automatically include the LoF and the LoT in the table of contents.
3. The [`afterpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package can be used to produce the corresponding headings in every page of the ToC, the LoF and the LoT; since these lists typically span few pages, one can use

   ```
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{tocheading}}
   \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{lofheading}}
   \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\afterpage{lotheading}}
   ```

   respectively, in the appropriate locations in the body of the document.
4. I used the `book` document class (instead of using `report`) to profit from the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` (and `\backmatter`) commands.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Change the name of the ToC
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}}

% Headings for every page of ToC, LoF and Lot
\newcommand\tocheading{\par\bigskip\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\hfill Page\par}
\newcommand\lofheading{\par\bigskip\figurename\hfill Page\par}
\newcommand\lotheading{\par\bigskip\MakeUppercase{\tablename}\hfill Page\par}

% Centering titles for the ToC, Lof and Lot
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

% Chapter entries formatting for frontmatter chapters
\newcommand\frontmatterchaptoc{%
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
  {\contentslabel{1.5em}\MakeUppercase}
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}\MakeUppercase}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
}

% Chapter entries formatting for mainmatter chapters
\newcommand\mainmatterchaptoc{%
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [5em]{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
  {\contentslabel{3em}\hspace*{-1em}\MakeUppercase}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
}

% Section, subsection, table and figure entries formatting
\titlecontents{section}
  [7em]{}{\hspace{-1em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [7.5em]{}{\hspace{-1em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{figure}
  [5em]{}
  {\contentslabel{3em}\hspace*{-1em}}{}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{table}
  [5em]{}
  {\contentslabel{3em}\hspace*{-1em}}{}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\frontmatterchaptoc % activation of chapter entries formatting in the frontmatter

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addtocontents{lof}{\lofheading}% add heading to the first page in LoF
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addtocontents{lot}{\lotheading}% add heading to the first page in LoT
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\tocheading}% add heading to the first page in ToC, after frontmatter entries

\mainmatterchaptoc% activation of chapter entries formatting in the mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section One One}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure one}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Policy divergence and traditional research}
\section{Section Two One}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{William Adolphe Bouguereau, \emph{Youth of Bacchus}  (initial sketch), 1884}
\label{fig:wab}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Section Two One One}

\end{document}
```

An image of the obtained ToC:

[image]

an Image of the obtained LoF:

[image]

Comment: WOW. This is awesome. Thank you so much for taking time with my problem.

I'm getting this error when I compile. 

Package tocloft Note: The document has chapter divisions.
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

I'm using these packages http://pastebin.com/2C4A2dQC (due to limit character)

Comment: @knguyen you're using the obslote `subfigure` package (in fact, you are loading it twice in the preamble); this package shouldn't be used anymore; you can use [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or even better, [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your TOC/etc ends up taking multiple pages, use \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\flushleft\protect\afterpage{tocheading}} to override TOC default indenting.

Hoping to save future thesis editors some Googling time.

Comment: Using `\afterpage` would isolate the heading fix to only the following page. What if the ToC spans 3 (or more) pages?

Comment: I had this exact problem.  The "ugly" hack I ended up using was compiling it once, seeing which chapter heading was the last one on page 2 (or 3, etc), then throwing in another one of these commands after the \chapter call.  It will correctly format the TOC as desired, but the behavior will change if the document gets significantly longer/shorter in places.  It's not pretty, but it works.

I would welcome a more elegant solution if anyone has one.

Comment: A better way would be to use [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) or [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) which is executed at every `\shipout` to insert content (perhaps using [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage)). Then, once the ToC is completed, to stop the insertion. For example, see [Table of Contents with headings on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72986/5764).