# Table of Contents with headings on every page

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my doctoral thesis using LaTeX and now I face the following problems.

On every page of the ToC, the headings must be printed. For example, on the first page and consecutive pages of the ToC, I want the following to be printed:

```
**Chapter no                Contents                     Page no**
```

The same applies to List of Figures and List of Tables.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Follow-up question: [Table of Contents modifications required](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73658/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following minimal example creates a `report` with a `\tableofcontents` to your specifications using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=30\baselineskip]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocheader}{{%
  \bfseries% Font selection
  \hspace*{\cftchapindent}% Chapter indent
  \makebox[\cftchapnumwidth][l]{Chapter no}% Chapter number heading
  \hfill%
  \contentsname% Title heading
  \hfill%
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][r]{Page}% Page heading
  \par\kern.5\baselineskip% After heading
  }}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup%
  \parindent\z@\parskip\cftparskip%
  \tocheader%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \endgroup%
}}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\par\kern.5\baselineskip\tocheader}
\newcommand{\AtBeginShipoutClear}{\gdef\AtBegShi@Hook{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}
\tableofcontents
\AtBeginShipoutClear

\chapter{abcd}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{bcde}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{cdef}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{defg}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{efgh}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{fghi}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{ghji}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{hjik}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{jikl}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{iklm}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{klmn}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{lmno}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{mnop}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{nopq}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{opqr}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{pqrs}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{qrst}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{rstu}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{stuv}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{tuvw}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{uvwx}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{vwxy}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\chapter{wxyz}\section{First}\section{Second}\section{Last}
\end{document}
```

`\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}` adds `\tocheader` (the `Chapter no...Contents...Page` construction) to every page, while `\AtBeginShipoutClear` removes it from subsequent pages. `\tocheader` constructs its contents based on the spacing offered by `tocloft`: An indent of `\cftchapindent`, followed by the chapter number (of width `\cftchapnumwidth`), centred heading and page number of width `\@pnumwidth`. It also possible to do this in a slightly more manual way using [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) (see [Add 'Page' above page numbers in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8296/5764)).

The same can be done for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, although it would be bizarre to add `Chapter no` to a contents that doesn't list any chapters.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package to define a page style for the ToC (a similar style can be defined for the LoF and the LoT):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=14cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% style for the ToC
\fancypagestyle{liststyle}
{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries Chapter No}
\fancyhead[C]{\bfseries\contentsname}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries Page No}
}

% style for regular pages
\fancypagestyle{regularstyle}
{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \pagestyle{liststyle}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{regularstyle}

\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}\section{Test}\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The dimensions chosen for `paperwidth` and `paperheight` through the `geometry` package are just for convenience in the example and have no relevance in the solution.