# Table of Contents modifications required

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried latex code for generating toc suggested by stack exchange in response to my previous query  . Still I need small modifications. In the first page of toc, At top middle “TABLE OF CONTENTS” is required and then in the second line 3 column names such as “CHAPTER NO.”, “TITLE” and “PAGE NO.” are required. In subsequent pages only the said second line particulars are required. The same applies to List of tables and List of figures. 
[image]

Comment: Related question: [Table of Contents with headings on every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72986/5764)

Comment: Where do you want the titles to appear? below the title heading?

Comment: @HarishKumar Below the title heading.Please follow  question  titled "Indenting in Table of contents in new style required" as i added it with MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a modification to [Table of Contents with headings on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72991/5764) that adapts the solution to the three contents elements of a `report`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=30\baselineskip]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionsandtablesandfigures}{
  \section{First}
  \begin{table}[ht]\caption{A first table}\end{table}\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{A first figure}\end{figure}
  \section{Second}
  \begin{table}[ht]\caption{A second table}\end{table}\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{A second figure}\end{figure}
  \section{Last}
  \begin{table}[ht]\caption{A last table}\end{table}\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{A last figure}\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\tocheader}{{%
  \bfseries% Font selection
  %\hspace*{\cftchapindent}% Chapter indent
  \makebox[\cftchapnumwidth][l]{Chapter no}% Chapter number heading
  \hfill%
  Title% Title heading
  \hfill%
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][r]{Page}% Page heading
  \par\kern.5\baselineskip% After heading
  }}
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}% No dots for \section in ToC
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}% No skip before ToC title
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0pt}% No skip after ToC title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large\hfill}%\contentsname
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\null\par\kern.5\baselineskip\tocheader\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{20pt}% Chapter indent in ToC is 20pt
\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\bfseries Chapter no\end{lrbox}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\dimexpr\wd\@tempboxa-\cftchapindent}% Chapter num width in ToC
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{\wd\@tempboxa}% Section indent in ToC
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\dimexpr\cftsecindent+\cftsecnumwidth}
% LIST OF FIGURES
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\cleardoublepage\bfseries\Large\hfill}%\listfiguresname
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill\null\par\kern.5\baselineskip\tocheader\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}}
% LIST OF TABLES
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\cleardoublepage\bfseries\Large\hfill}%\listtablesname
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill\null\par\kern.5\baselineskip\tocheader\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}}

\newcommand{\AtBeginShipoutClear}{\gdef\AtBegShi@Hook{}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\AtBeginShipoutClear}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\AtBeginShipoutClear}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\AtBeginShipoutClear}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\chapter{abcd}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{bcde}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{cdef}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{defg}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{efgh}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{fghi}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{ghji}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{hjik}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{jikl}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{iklm}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{klmn}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{lmno}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{mnop}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{nopq}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{opqr}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{pqrs}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{qrst}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{rstu}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{stuv}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{tuvw}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{uvwx}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{vwxy}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\chapter{wxyz}\sectionsandtablesandfigures
\end{document}
```

The following modifications may still be required:

- If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark), one should add the relevant information to the contents macros (`\tableofcontents`, `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`). Currently they're not set as `\chapter*` the way they're used to.
- Depending on where your last floats are, it may be required to use [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) to finalize processing of floats and obtain an accurate ToC/LoT/LoF.
- Adding the ToC/LoF/LoT to the ToC.
- Modifying the page styles (which includes the page numbering) surrounding the ToC/LoF/LoT. Easily done using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), if need be.
- Additional indentation of sectional units beyond `\subsection` to line up properly. However, a base has been established up to `\subsection` which is easily extendible.

Comment: thank you very much Werner. Your solution works well and new problem arose in the indent numbering of Chapter, section ,subsection and subsubsection. Can you please refer the instructions of the university at page no.44  of 47[ANNEXURE 40] and the link is  given below
http://www.annauniv.edu/research1/PhDRegulations_2010.pdf   
 The solution suggested by you gives same level of indenting for all chapters, sections, subsections and subsubsections. Also, dotted lines are not required. Please suggest.

Comment: @vivek: This is going to take a little while to incorporate. For future reference, include these details from the start.

Comment: @vivek: I've added some changes. It's still not clear to me how the LoT/LoF (that doesn't have chapters) has to look with a `Chapter no` reference. As such, I've left it as-is.

Comment: Thanks Werner. The Solution works fine. i will manipulate those Chapter no. in LoT/LoF as Table no. and Figure no.Thanks.