# Table of Contents with headings

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to know how to create a Table of Contents like the one below using LaTeX:

```
                             TABLE OF CONTENT
             CHAPTER            TITLE              PAGE NO
                             ABSTRACT                 i
                             LIST OF TABLES           ii
                1            INTRODUCTION             1
                             1.1 Abc                  1
                             1.2 Rtcfgc               2
                2            LITERATURE SURVEY        8
                             2.1Xyz                   8
```

Please, anyone help me in this.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  The documentclass and some of the packages you load may determine which solutions are viable and which will not work.

Comment: You are saying that the common `\tableofcontents` command is not what you want, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Add column headings for ToC entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79814/5764) (original source: [Table of Contents modifications required](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73658/5764))

Comment: This seems a good question to me. What the OP wants, seems a `tabular of contents`. The layout is nice, if you use short titles for your chapter and section titles.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a first start, using [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) and [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable). The idea is to tell `etoc` chapters and sections to fill-up  a token list variable with the lines of the `longtable`. Then the `longtable` environment is typeset at the end of this process.

```
         %                TABLE OF CONTENT
         % CHAPTER            TITLE              PAGE NO
         %                 ABSTRACT                 i
         %                 LIST OF TABLES           ii
         %    1            INTRODUCTION             1
         %                 1.1 Abc                  1
         %                 1.2 Rtcfgc               2
         %    2            LITERATURE SURVEY        8
         %                 2.1Xyz                   8

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newtoks\toctoks
\newtoks\tmptoks

% This appends to a token list variable given as first argument
% the once expanded second argument
\newcommand*{\appendtotok}[2]
% #1=token list variable defined with \newtoks, %
% #2=macro,
{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the\expandafter #1#2}}


% document is assumed not to contain `\part' 

% it is a bit complicated to get the chapter to inscribe the uppercased version,
% together with the hyperref link, inside the \toctoks which will be injected
% into a longtable
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {}
  {\appendtotok\toctoks {\etocthelinkednumber &}%
   \tmptoks\expandafter{\expandafter\etocthelink\expandafter{\expandafter
                        \MakeUppercase\expandafter{\etocthename}}}%
   \expandafter\appendtotok\expandafter\toctoks\expandafter{\the\tmptoks &}%
   \appendtotok\toctoks{\etocthelinkedpage \\\relax}}
  {}

\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {}
  {\toctoks\expandafter{\the\toctoks &}%
   \appendtotok\toctoks{\etocthelinkednumber\ }%
   \appendtotok\toctoks{\etocthelinkedname &}%
   \appendtotok\toctoks{\etocthelinkedpage \\\relax}}
  {}

\etocsettocstyle
   {%
      \centerline{\large\bfseries TABLE OF CONTENTS}
      \toctoks {\hspace*{1cm}\textbf{CHAPTER}\hspace*{1cm}&
                \hspace*{1cm}\textbf{TITLE}\hspace*{1cm}&
                \hspace*{1em}\textbf{PAGE NO}\hspace*{1em}\\\relax }%
   }
   {\begin{longtable}{clc}\the\toctoks\end{longtable}}

% alternative: put above \global\toctoks\expandafter{\the\toctoks}
% and the typeset the longtable at your convenience, after \tableofcontents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
% only chapters and sections.

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter {Abstract}

\chapter {List of tables}

%    \chapter {List of figures}
% or rather, perhaps:
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}


\mainmatter

\chapter {Introduction}

\section {Abc}

\section {Rtcfgc}

\chapter {Literature survey}

\section {Xyz}

\end{document}
```

[image: toc]