# Adding a line to the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add a line to a table of content. The line would say  something like

Chapter(on the left)     and  Page (on the right)

with addcontentsline I get a page number which I do not want.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Add column headings for ToC entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79814/5764) or ultimately [Table of Contents modifications required](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73658/5764)