# "Contents" heading on more than one page in LyX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I'm using LyX. I have a 2 page table of contents, and Id like the header ("Contents") to appear on both pages
I tried this:

[Table of Contents with headings on every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72986/table-of-contents-with-headings-on-every-page)

by putting the code in the preamble - and by wrapping the "Table Of contents" list with ERT that contains `\AtBeginShipout{\tocheader}` and `\AtBeginShipoutClear` after the "Table Of contents".

Nothing worked! 
I'm using the `article` class.

Answer (score 4):

Load the package `afterpage`

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

and add these two lines after your `\tableofcontents`

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\hspace*{-1.5em}\bfseries\Large \contentsname}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\vspace*{10pt}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\hspace*{-1.5em}\bfseries\Large \contentsname}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{\vspace*{10pt}}}

\newpage

\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]